# SwiftUI: InsetGroupedListStyle List and full-width header

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

How to make a full-width header using List with InsetGroupedListStyle on iOS?
One way is to use negative padding (as an example in my code), but this doesn't seem like the best solution using fixed value as it may change in the future.

Is there a better way?

Example code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section (header:
                        VStack {
                            Text("Header")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                        .frame( // This doesn't remove list's paddings
                              minWidth: 0,
                              maxWidth: .infinity,
                              minHeight: 0,
                              maxHeight: .infinity,
                              alignment: .topLeading
                            )
                        .background(Color.red)
//                      .padding(.horizontal, -16) // This works, but fixed value is not the best solution.
                        .textCase(nil)
                        .font(.body)
            ) {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
            }
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could set the `width` of the header to the `width` of the screen, and the padding (x2) you need could be reduced from the width. To can achieve this using a `GeometryReader`. For example,

```
// Geometry reader to get the width
GeometryReader { reader in
    List {
        Section (header:
            VStack {
                Text("Header")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            // Setting the frame of the Header to the size of the screen
            // Reducing 20 from the width, giving a padding of 10 on each side
            .frame(width: reader.size.width - 20, height: 20, alignment: .leading)
            .background(Color.red)
            .textCase(nil)
            .font(.body)
            ) {
                Text("Hello, world!")
                    .padding()
            }
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
}
```

You can see the result below

[image]

Comment: It works! Thanks :) In my case I don't want to have padding at all so this will work for me:
`.frame(width: reader.size.width, height: 20, alignment: .leading)`
But it's very good that you've showed me this option. Might be useful another time. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped ;)

Answer (score 2):

you could try this:

```
...
{
  Text("Hello, world!").padding()
}.headerProminence(.increased)     // <--- here
```

Comment: Seems like a good idea, but I am getting an error. I think it is iOS 15.0+. I am using 14 at the moment.

Comment: ha yes, I'm on macos 12 targeting ios 15. Maybe there is something similar in ios 14.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll a little. Maybe someone has another idea. If not, I guees your answer is on point and I just need to wait for iOS 15 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple way

```
       ZStack {
            Color.bgPrimary.ignoresSafeArea()
            List {
                Section {
                    ForEach(1...19,id:\.self) { i in
                        ListRow(title: "list \(i)")
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("23 Jan 2023")
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,alignment: .leading)
                }
            }
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden) //if needed
        }
```

give full width to text frame then apply native padding can solve the issue.
place the text inside container with leading, trailing and center as you like currently I am using leading